# ¿Como cambiar el idioma a GitLab?

Tags: linux, debian, gitlab

Tengo un servidor GitLab local en mi empresa, la cual instalé en un contenedor de Proxmox VE 5.1, el servidor lo instalé bajo Debian 9.3 (Stretch).

El asunto es que cuando intento cambiar el idioma predeterminado (Inglés) a Español en la configuración del perfil del usuario, dice que lo hace correctamente, sin embargo nunca se traduce.

Pienso que puedo hacerlo a través de algún archivo de configuración cambiando el idioma predeterminado. ¿Cuál es este archivo, o qué debo hacer?

PD: La instalación la hice manualmente mediante el script de instalación de la página oficial de GitLab.

Comment: Si lees te darás cuentas que esa opción esta dentro de tu perfil lo que indica es la lengua que hablas. No es una opción para traducir GitLab al castellano.

Comment: si pudiste hacerlo? yo estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que ir a configuracion - preference - location y ahi pones spanish o el idioma que prefieras